# How to store an array into an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

Let's say I have a fixed size 3 of array that stores the RGB of color.
Example:

```
color[3] = {0, 0, 255}
```

and I have another array, arrayOfColors that stores many colors. 
Example:

```
arrayOfColors = { {0, 0, 255}, {0, 0, 0}, {255, 255, 255} }
```

I'm not sure what is the best way to do this but I've tried something. But I have errors when I do this approach. Please help me out, I'm very new to C language. Thank you in advance!

```
unsigned char color1[3] = {0, 0, 0};
unsigned char color2[3] = {0, 255, 255};

unsigned char *rowColors = NULL;
rowColors = (unsigned char*)malloc((2) * sizeof(char));
rowColors[0] = color1;
rowColors[1] = color2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
unsigned char *rowColors = NULL;
```

`rowColors` is a *unsigned character pointer* i.e `rowColors[0]` is a single character and a *character can not hold character buffer* like below

```
rowColors[0] = color1; /* rowColors[0] is a char, it can't hold char buffer color1 */
rowColors[1] = color2;
```

If you wish to store multiple character buffer like `color1` and `color2` into `rowColors`, it should either of `unsigned char**` type or ***array of pointers*** not just `unsigned char*` type.

Sample code

```
unsigned char color1[3] = {0, 0, 0};
unsigned char color2[3] = {0, 255, 255};

unsigned char *rowColors[2]; /* USE ARRAY OF POINTERS */
for(int row = 0;row < 2; row++) {
    rowColors[row] = malloc(MAX_EACH_BUF_SIZE)); /* ALLOCATE MEMORY FOR EACH POINTER FIRST, define MAX_EACH_BUF_SIZE value accordingly */
}
/* AND THEN STORE INTO ARRAY OF POINTER */
rowColors[0] = color1;
rowColors[1] = color2;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer that I was looking for :), sorry I can't upvote your post because I don't have enough reputation points

Comment: @Thomas I'm glad about the fact that my answer helped you. You are welcome on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can do using `C structure`. This doesn't describe the process of declaring an array inside another array but it will serve your purpose.

You need to declare a structure type object first. Then make an array of that structure.  See bellow example for better understanding:

```
struct RGBColor
{
  unsigned int R, G, B;
};

RGBColor arrayOfColors[] = { {0, 0, 255}, {0, 0, 0}, {255, 255, 255} };

int main ()
{
  int len = sizeof (arrayOfColors) / sizeof (arrayOfColors[0]);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      printf ("{%d, %d, %d}\n", arrayOfColors[i].R, arrayOfColors[i].G,
          arrayOfColors[i].B);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
{0, 0, 255}
{0, 0, 0}
{255, 255, 255}
```

Comment: The returned type from `sizeof()` is a `size_t`, not an `int`

Comment: This answer is missing the statement: `#include <stdio.h>`.   Suggest not expecting a beginner in C to know this

Comment: @kamolHasan thank you! but if I want to send the arrayOfColors with the struct RGBColor type to other processor, what datatype should I pass in? 
For example:

MPI_Send(arrayOfColors, 3,   ?DATATYPE?,   0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

Answer (score 1):

Remember that unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, array *expressions* like `color1` and `color2` will be converted (“decay”) from expressions of type “N-element array of `T`” to “pointer to `T`”, and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  So in an expression like

```
x = color1;
```

the type of `x` needs to be `unsigned char *`.  So you can start by setting up an array of `unsigned char *` to store the addresses of separate arrays like `color1` and `color2`:

```
unsigned char *colors[2];

colors[0] = colors1;
colors[1] = colors2;
```

However, what might ultimately be simpler is just setting up an Nx3 array of `unsigned char`:

```
unsigned char colors[N][3];  // for some N

memcpy( colors[0], color1, sizeof color1 );
```

To allocate it dynamically, use

```
unsigned char (*colors)[3] = malloc( sizeof *colors * N );
```

and you can access each element like a regular array:

```
colors[0][0] = color1[0];
```