# How to store a array in another array in C

Tags: arrays, c, variable-assignment

So I want store an array named buffer into an array into an array called first_line
That is what I tried:

`first_line = buffer;`

It's obvisly that this does not work. I know that an array has many parts but how do I store it all together in one variable?

I'm a totally beginner in C and dont know what I am doing could someone help me?

Comment: Show how the arrays are  declared and what they store,

Comment: I got the code from https://codeforwin.org/2018/01/c-program-read-and-display-file-contents.html line 43 you will see it

Comment: You haven't shown enough code for us to accurately help, but I'll say this much. Let's assume your `buffer` array stores `char`s. Then it would be of type `char []`. If you want to store an array of `char []`, then that array would be of type `char *[]`. Provide some code and we can help ensure you allocate memory for these types correctly.

Comment: See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57645491/how-to-store-an-array-into-an-array-in-c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy a char array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645583/how-to-copy-a-char-array-in-c)

Comment: As a total beginner you should probably read a bit more before you start asking specific questions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays do not have the assignment operator.

If you have character arrays that store strings then you can use for example functions `strcpy` , `strncpy` or `memcpy` declared in header `<string.h>` to copy a string from one array into another.

For example

```
#include <string.h>

//...

char s1[] = "Hello";
char s2[sizeof( s1 )];

strcpy( s2, s1 );
```

To copy arrays that do not store strings you can use either function `memcpy` or some kind of a loop to copy element by element from one array in another.